# Is Console in Inspect Dangerous?

Tags: google-chrome, console, xss, developer-tools

Can I get hacked after writing something in the "console" part after clicking "inspect"? A YouTube video showed a person writing `Runner.instance.gameOver = function(){};` in the dinosaur game's console part after clicking on "inspect". I did that (because this "hack" does not harm others) and the game did become easy. However, the day after that, I heard that console can be dangerous, can you please help me? I am VERY concerned.

Comment: It's called [Self-XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-XSS). You should definitely be careful when you execute code that others give you. `Runner.instance.gameOver = function(){};` won't do any damage to you though. Noting to worry about in this case.

Comment: Thank you VERY much. I REALLY appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Yes.

Pasting and running anything you don't understand from an untrusted source (i.e. basically everyone on the internet) is as bad in the console as it is anywhere else. In practice, someone malicious could trick you into [Self-XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-XSS), effectively hijacking your account on the current browser tab.

This is why e.g. Facebook injects a warning message whenever you open the console on their page:

[image]

That being said: If you know what you are doing, using the console is perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you please suggest to me what to do, and is what I wrote (Runner.instance._gameOver = function(){};) dangerous? I don't understand code. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: As @Ivar already said: What you wrote will not cause any harm. But then again I am also merely another untrusted source on the internet, so in general: When in doubt, don't paste. And unless you understand the code you should always be in doubt.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
Runner.instance.gameOver = function(){};
```

The code is just replacing the method gameOver by a function what does nothing.

What this means? The original function what is designed to stop you playing when you lose, is no there anymore so you can't lose at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I  really appreciate it.